# How to Play HD Youtube Video

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

If I apply this code error shows Can't play this video How I can play this video

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri uri= Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdrTQmsxzpU");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

**Error**

```
mTotalSize is -1
 setReadTimeOut =  30000ms
message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
05-02 15:43:21.686 426-439/com.example.muhammad.youtubeproject E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)

V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
 Error (1,-2147483648)
Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `YouTubePlayerView` Instead of `Video View`.

`It is more Reliable to Play YouTube Videos.`

**Here is quick Starting Snippet.**

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

**Code Snippet.**

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    // YouTube player view
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

        // Initializing video player with developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

            // Hiding player controls
            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

}
```

**Here is Reference Link** [Look.](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/)

Comment: It show me error on this
YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener

Comment: @Ahmad Look at the reference link i have given at last in my answer. step by step information given.